# Launch Terminal using BetterTouchTool

Tags: bettertouchtool

How would I open Terminal using BetterTouchTool? I tried using predefined action: open application, but I can't seem to find the Terminal app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open an ssh session in terminal with BetterTouchTool](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228333/open-an-ssh-session-in-terminal-with-bettertouchtool)

Comment: The Terminal app is located in: `/Applications/Utilities`

Answer (score 2):

Use the action "Run Apple Script" for example as a keyboard shortcut and use the following code:

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script
```

Comment: If you want to open a new window (instead of switching to any existing window) then you can use     tell application "Terminal"  
    do script " "  
    activate  
end tell

Answer (score -1):

As user3439894 said, have you tried looking for Terminal in the Utilities folder rather than the applications folder. Hope This Helps :)